# JSON - Adding an array of type Double getting encoded

Tags: java, arrays, json, mongodb, jax-rs

I am trying to add a array of double is (size 2) to a JSON object. This is basically a location information ( which has longitude and latitude info).

The code is below

```
double latLong[] = {124.6682391, -17.8978304};
final BasicDBObject loc = new BasicDBObject();
loc.put("type","Point");
loc.put("coordinates", latLong);
jsonObject.put("location", loc);
```

After adding when I tried printing it I am getting the following output.

```
"location" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : "[D@53e21fa6"}
```

Not sure what to do with this. I am expecting

```
"location" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : [124.6682391, -17.8978304"]}
```

Not sure why the array is getting encoded. Is there a way to avoid this as I cannot insert the encoded info to DB.

Thanks a lot for your help and your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `latlong[]` is an `Array`, but `latlong` is just like the reference（long* latLong）, you put the reference `location` to json, so you got it's location not the value. 
You can use the fastJson utils to change `latlong[]` to jsonString first.

Comment: Thanks. I am lookinn into FastJSON documentation.Will update you ASAP once I crack it.

Comment: Thanks once again. Struggled but was not able to crack it. Not sure why. Do you have a code sample. Not able to find the API in FastJSON to  accomplish this task. Any pointers will be really helpful for me

Comment: I got the crux of the issue. It is passing the reference as you said. So, I am trying to pass the array object as it is. But not able to find  how to do it. Thanks once again for  your help

Comment: FastJSON is tied to .NET if I am not wrong. I am using JAVA. But Thanks for the answer. I got to know where the issue is.

Comment: hi, fastjson can also be used in JAVA, and it's useful in solving json problems. here is the code sample, wish it can help u. 
import com.alibaba.fastjson.*;
                double latLong[] = { 124.6682391, -17.8978304 };
  JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject loc = new JSONObject();
  loc.put("type", "Point");
  loc.put("coordinates", latLong);
  location.put("location", loc);
  String str = location.toJSONString();
  System.out.println(str);